# Dockerize Logstash, Redis setup

Tags: redis, docker, logstash, paas

Have a `Logstash` process using file as input sending events to `Redis` and from there to second `Logstash` process and over to custom http process.
So, `Logstash --> Redis --> Logstash --> Http`
In order to dockerize the setup I was thinking of keeping `Logstash --> Redis` on one container and `linking` that with `Redis --> Http` which will be on another container.
Am still new to Docker & Would highly appreciate any inputs / feedback on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my opinion of how I would go about this.
One Logstash image that maybe takes the configuration through a mapped volumn or even a passed Env Parameter that switchs between file input and redis input.

So you would have two Logstash containers, from the same image one takes input form a file and pushes it to redis and the second from redis and puts it out to your http interface.

And a Redis Container that acts as a go between/cache.

Hope this makes sense.